# How to define headers in a swagger domain

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swaggerhub

I'm trying to define some reusable elements in a SwaggerHub domain but can't figure out how to define headers.

I've tried a few things but they all produce errors, such as:

- $refs cannot match any of the following: "*#/definitions*",
  "*#/parameters*"
- should be a object
- requires property "type"
- additionalProperty "$ref" exists in when not allowed

Full example here:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/domains/batwad/domain-demo/1.0.0

```yaml
definitions:
  error-list:
    description: Standard error response
    type: object
    properties:
      errors:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        readOnly: true

responses:
  bad-request:
    description: Bad request
    headers:
      # these don't error, but the UI docs say "Could not render this component"
      X-Transaction-ID:
        description: Transaction correlation identifier.
        type: string
      Content-Type:
        description: Must be <tt>application/json</tt>
        type: string
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/error-list'

  server-error:
    description: Unexpected error
    headers:
      # says "should be an object" and "cannot match any of blablabla"
      - $ref: '#/parameters/x-transaction-id'
      - $ref: '#/parameters/content-type'
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/error-list'

  service-unavailable:
    description: Service temporarily unavailable
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/error-list'
    headers:
      # says "requires property 'type'" and "$ref not allowed"
      X-Transaction-ID:
        $ref: '#/parameters/x-transaction-id'
      Content-Type:
        $ref: '#/parameters/content-type'

parameters:

  x-transaction-id:
    name: X-Transaction-ID
    in: header
    description: Transaction correlation identifier.
    required: true
    type: string

  content-type:
    name: Content-Type
    in: header
    description: Must be <tt>application/json</tt>
    required: true
    type: string
```

Comment: Related: [Swagger header definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40223429/113116), [Swagger / Open API 2.0 can I declare a common response header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35218774/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bad-request` response definition is the correct one, and other responses should be changed to look the same. That is, the response headers must be defined inline – this is a limitation of the OpenAPI 2.0 Specification, it does not support $ref'erencing response headers.

$ref'erencing response headers is [possible in OpenAPI 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476201/113116), but as of this writing (December 2018) SwaggerHub does not support OAS3 syntax in domains yet.

As for "Could not render this component", <s>this is a display bug in SwaggerHub. Send a bug report via the in-app support chat. That said, API definitions that use responses from domains are rendered correctly.</s>
**UPD:** this has been fixed as of February 2019.

Comment: Shame about not being able to $ref headers, that really hampers the usefulness of reusable definitions.  I will look into OAS3, thanks